# Effects collateral REPLACE MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm doing tests with two distinct database tables, where I'll run a CRON every X seconds to run a PHP script I did. I did many tests working with many lines (3,000,000+) In the more optimized code I got, checking to see if it contains update / insert from table X to Y, it took 17 seconds.

When I removed the check on UPDATE / INSERT and replaced for REPLACE the time decreased to an incredible 4 seconds.

My question is regarding the effects of this because so fast and I do not see many people using it? As this is a table from the Database X to a Table of the Database Y, to check for update will be by PRIMARY KEY, that is, it will not contain Auto Increment.

**RESUME**: I need to synchronize one table with another, running the script with REPLACE, I was incredibly faster than checking to see if it contains update and inserting. What is the real disadvantage of replace?

Comment: You're going to need to clear this up some as I cannot understand what your actual question is.

Comment: Added an resumin @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the SQL statements you used.

It may be that the `REPLACE` is *not* equivalent.

Consider using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`; it is *likely* to be faster than `REPLACE`.

`REPLACE` is actually the combo of two commands -- `DELETE` based on any unique (or primary) keys, then `INSERT`.  `REPLACE` can actually shrink the number of rows!

"Synchronize" could imply that there are (or are not) any "new" rows.  And there are (or are not) rows to be deleted.  Different techniques succeed (or fail) depending on these details.  `REPLACE`, for example, probably cannot delete any rows during the sync.

If you are only `INSERTing` or `UPDATEing` (never `DELETEing`), see the two SQL statements in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization -- they may be even faster than your `REPLACE`.

If your new table is a complete replacement, why sync?  Why not `RENAME TABLE` -- which would take only milliseconds, and can be done without interruption.

Comment: Basically, I have 4 servers to stay ahead of the Master, because the way it is now it is well overloaded, and I do not have much money to buy other good servers. My idea was to put 4 servers to receive at most 30,000 rows and send them in the PHP script I'm doing to the main server.

 I tried with the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but it's time too. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Read the rest of that link I gave you -- it talks about how to receive thousands of rows per second on a single server.